# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. how to fix this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function App() {
  return <StrictMode>{data.map(creatcard)}</StrictMode>
}
function creatcard(characters) {
  return (
    <Card
      id={characters._id}
      name={characters.name}
      about={characters.about}
      img={characters.img}
    ></Card>
  )
}
```

Here is my card component

```
function Card(pops) {
  return (
    <div className="cards" key={pops.id}>
      <div className="subhead">
        <h1>{pops.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <p>
        {abt.substring(0, 200)}
        <br></br> <Link to={`/${pops.name}`}>Read more...</Link>
      </p>
      <img id="dp" src={pops.img}></img>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. I've already set the key for each card in my card component.

Comment: Probably a simple `key={characters._id}` added to the `<Card/>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js

Comment: @BrianThompson i've tried giving id in card still not working

Comment: That's not what I suggested, or what the error says. You have to give it a `key` prop. `key` is a special prop that only React uses. `id` is your own that will get passed like normal to the `Card` component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key should be in the direct Component render of a map function. And your key must not have duplicates. If your IDs might have some duplicates, you can easily concat with an index to solve the warning.

```
function App() { return (
   <StrictMode>
    {data.map(creatcard) }
   </StrictMode>
 )
}

function creatcard(characters, index){
return(
  <Card 
     key={character._id} // or key={character._id + '' + index}
     id={characters._id}
     name={characters.name}
     about={characters.about}
     img={characters.img}
  />
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `key` prop that react is asking for should be applied as a prop on your `<Card/>` component usage and not inside the `Card` component. Here's what I mean;

```
   function App() { 
     return (
        <StrictMode>
         {data.map(creatcard)}
        </StrictMode>
      )
    }

function creatcard(characters){
 return(
   <Card 
      key={characters._id}
      id={characters._id}
      name={characters.name}
      about={characters.about}
      img={characters.img}
    ></Card>
)};
```

React uses the `key` prop in list rendering to identify each list items uniquely. React needs this key to efficiently update the UI when items are added, updated or removed from the list. Hope this helps.